# AI, State Machine - how to expand a state machine to handle multiple monsters?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, state-machine

I'm reading [this excellent article on how to create a state machine for ai purposes](http://roguebasin.roguelikedevelopment.org/index.php?title=Roguelike_Intelligence_-_Intrinsic_Information_and_State_Machine_AIs). Unfortunately I'm having trouble understanding how to expand the state machine listed below. The pseudocode for this example appears to ask the state machine for an action for the current state:

```
do_stateless_ai(statemachine[action][currentstate]);
```

What does this mean if I need to implement multiple monster AIs?

Do I create one state machine implementation and just load it with different state tables like below?

or

Do I code unique state machines for each monster?

or

Do I create one massive state table if I have multiple monsters? Sorry if this question appears very amateurish, this is the first time I'm trying to implement AI.

Here's the artificial intelligence state table described in the article:

DRAGON AI (partial)

```
  State:  Obs: Action:          input L    input M    input H   NULL

  SLEEPING L   asleep-ai        WAKING:1              HUNGRY:1
  WAKING   C   none                        ENRAGED:1  HUNGRY:1  CURIOUS:1
  ENRAGED  C   typical-ai, p1                                   WAKING:1
  HUNGRY   C   typical-ai, p2              ENRAGED:1
  CURIOUS  A   curious-ai                  ENRAGED:1  HUNGRY:1  BORED:0.1
```

And here is the pseudocode for the implementation of this machine:

```
acted = 0;
while (!acted)
{
    observe(statemachine[obs][currentstate]);
    shifted = 0;
    for (inputs=FIRSTINPUT; inputs < LASTINPUT && !shifted; inputs++)
    {
       if (input_is_true(input))
       {  /* note that what's stored in the statemachine is an expression, 
             not necessarily just a number. getshiftprob substitute in 
             values from the monster's extrinsic info and solves the expr.*/
          probshift = getshiftprob 
                 (statemachine[input][currentstate].probshift);
          if random() < probshift
          {
             currentstate = statemachine[input][currentstate].state;
             shifted = 1;
          }
       }
    }
    if statemachine[action][currentstate] != NULL
    {
       do_stateless_ai(statemachine[action][currentstate]);
       acted = 1;
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use one gigantic table then you end up with one gigantic AI controlling everything directly.  But think a little bit about what that table and implementation would look like, even for two agents-- think about the combination of states and observations, and how large that table would grow even for two or three agents.  I think you will come to the conclusion that that is not really feasible.  It may not even be desirable.

If you have multiple tables, then you have multiple agents that are all independently controlled, and which are of a more reasonable size.  It is not obvious to me why you would want unique machinery for each agent.  Even if you want different behaviors, which means different tables, you should still be able to come up with some generic infrastructure that you can personalize easily.